# Illegal start of expression, declaring public static String with array and int parameters?

Tags: java

I am making a hangman game for school (learning java). We just began using methods in our programs and I attempted to make a method that will take an int value and an array value and output a pseudorandomly generated value from the array.

I have attempted to change around my variables, check if declaring a public static String is an unacceptable method, and I tried looking into how arrays work with methods but I am stumped. I have already checked to make sure my previous code is not errored so it has to be the method declaration that is the problem.

```
public static String generateTopic (int index2T, String[][] hangmanWords)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        index2T = rand.nextInt(10);
        String topic = hangmanWords[0][index2T];
        return topic;
    }
```

I know that my code within the method is correct, however, it is the method declaration that seems to be the problem and I am getting an error on NetBeans saying "Illegal start of expression".
Thanks for the help - Hannah

Comment: I'm guessing you have mismatched braces somewhere in your code; the code you posted here compiles fine

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this method.

Comment: Why are you passing `int index2T` as an argument when you assign it locally only?

Comment: Can we see *all* of the code?